# SQL Server Table Column from data

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to achieve sort of solution to the below table, as I need to make one of the rows in column as column

```
   sku  title   name       product_qty  ID  warehouse_id
   -----------------------------------------------------
   S001 Title 1 warehouse1  5           23        1
   S001 Title 1 warehouse2  95          23        2
   S001 Title 1 warehouse3  3           23        3
   S002 Title 2 warehouse1  1           24        1
   S002 Title 2 warehouse2  91          24        2
   S002 Title 2 warehouse3  0           25        3
```

and what I would like to achieve

```
 sku    title   name        
                warehouse 1 warehouse 2 warehouse 3
S001    Title 1     5            95         3
S002    Title 2     1            91         0
```

Comment: What is the logic for this ? Have u tried anything?

Comment: its report i try to make but i need to generate it from MSSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this ... solution...You need to pivot the data.

```
CREATE TABLE Pivots
(
     sku VARCHAR(10)
    ,title VARCHAR(10)  
    ,name VARCHAR(10)  
    ,product_qty INT
    ,ID  INT
    ,warehouse_id INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO Pivots VALUES
('S001','Title1','warehouse1',5  , 23 , 1),
('S001','Title1','warehouse2',95 , 23 , 2),
('S001','Title1','warehouse3',3  , 23 , 3),
('S002','Title2','warehouse1',1  , 24 , 1),
('S002','Title2','warehouse2',91 , 24 , 2),
('S002','Title2','warehouse3',0  , 25 , 3)
GO
```

**SOLUTION**

```
SELECT sku,title titlename,ISNULL(MAX(x.warehouse1),0) warehouse1 
    ,ISNULL(MAX(x.warehouse2),0) warehouse2 ,ISNULL(MAX(x.warehouse3),0) warehouse3 FROM Pivots p
PIVOT
(
    MAX(product_qty) FOR name IN ([warehouse1],[warehouse2],[warehouse3])
)x
GROUP BY sku,title
```

**OUTPUT**

```
sku        titlename  warehouse1  warehouse2  warehouse3
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
S001       Title1     5           95          3
S002       Title2     1           91          0

(2 rows affected)
```

**SOLUTION 2 - USING conditional aggregation**

```
SELECT sku,title titlename
,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'warehouse1' THEN product_qty END),0) warehouse1 
,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'warehouse2' THEN product_qty END),0) warehouse2 
,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'warehouse3' THEN product_qty END),0) warehouse3 
FROM Pivots p
GROUP BY sku,title
```

**OUTPUT**

```
sku        titlename  warehouse1  warehouse2  warehouse3
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
S001       Title1     5           95          3
S002       Title2     1           91          0

(2 rows affected)
```

Comment: This method is called *conditional aggregation* not cross apply.

Comment: Update the method name. Thanks

Comment: It would have been much better if you actually edited your first answer to include this second solution.

Comment: Done. Merge both the solutions to one.

Comment: thank you, but the warehouse is dynamic value sometimes 3 sometimes more, is there a solution for it?

Comment: For that you need to use the dynamic pivoting. Please follow this - https://msbiskills.com/2017/12/25/sql-puzzle-dynamic-pivot-puzzle/

Comment: Thank you @PawanKumar, the link was have the solution for what i need.

Comment: Glad to help as always. :)